# How to create a generic page for each user without a custom module?

Tags: 8, users

I'm looking for a way to create one basic page for all user's website (instead of creating one basic page by user). This basic page must manage an url with a variable component. When I will create this basic page, theses url will must be available :

```
http://mywebsite.com/thebasicpage/1
http://mywebsite.com/thebasicpage/2
http://mywebsite.com/thebasicpage/3
...
http://mywebsite.com/thebasicpage/n
```

The reason is : I created a block view with a contextual parameter. And the default value of this parameter is in the path component. By exemple, if a user go to the http://mywebsite.com/thebasicpage/4 , so the block view displays all contents authored by the user number 4 (uid)
(I don't want create a page view because there will be several bloc view in the "thebasicpage/*")

I know it is possible via a custom module, but is it possible with only the drupal administration panel?

Comment: That's Views pages with URL wildcards.

Comment: If you insist in a non programmatic solution that does not involve creating a node, then simply create a view, only add 1 field to it and hide field with CSS. `I don't want create a page view because there will be several bloc view in the "thebasicpage/*` So what? how is this a deal breaker??? unless you wanted to go with the better method of creating custom module where you wouldn't have to hide a field with CSS.

Comment: I'm a lazy programmer, but finaly, I create a simple custom module ;) As you said and after some searchs, its so much easier/simple via a custom module